# Проблема с преобразованием объекта в примитивное значение. При использовании метода valueOf

Tags: javascript, ооп

```js
const func = (arg) => {
  func.valueOf = () => 0;

  return func; 
};

func() + 1;
// Результат => 1
```

Первый вариант отрабатывает правильно, а второй не правильно. В чем ошибка?

```js
const func = (arg) => {
  const innerFunc = (arg1) => {
    innerFunc.valueOf = () => 0;
    return func;
  };
  return innerFunc; 
};

func() + 1;
// Результат => '(arg1) => {\n    inner.valueOf = () => 0;\n    return func;\n  }1'
```

Comment: Вы ни разу не вызвали innerFunc, так что у неё так и не появилось valueOf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во вором варианте вызовите `func()() + 1`, ведь там функция`valueOf` определена не у функции, которая возвращается при вызове `func`, а у функции, которая возвращается при вызове `innerFunc`, которая в свою очередь возвращается при вызове `func`.